# Is variable scoping different in mongoose callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My variable `cart` seems to be declared inside the callback block.

It works if I declare a new variable (like `newCart`) instead of reassigning it.

```
cartRouter.post('/', (req,res) => {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var cart = req.body.cart;

    User.find({ username }, (err, res_find) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        var user_id = res_find[0]._id;
        var cart = new Cart({ cart, user: user_id })

        cart.save((err_save, cart_save) => {
            if (err_save) {
                res.json({ "resultType": "failure", "resultMessage": err });
            } else {
                res.json({ "resultType": "success", "resultMessage": "Cart successfully saved." });
            }
        })
    })
}
```

In the line `var cart = new Cart({ cart, user: user_id })`, if I declare a new variable var newCart and then use it with `newCart.save()`instead of `cart.save()` it works, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: new Cart({ ...cart, user: user_id }), flat your body object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
var cart = new Cart({cart, user: user_id});
```

The scope of the variable `cart` is the callback function. Even in the initialization expression for the variable, it tries to use the local variable, not the one from the containing function. But since the variable hasn't yet been initialized, the value is `undefined`. It's essentially equivalent to writing:

```
var cart;
cart = new Cart({cart, user:user_id});
```

So you need to use a different variable name if you want to refer to the outer variable as well.

If you tried to use `let` instead of `var` you would actually get an error

> Cannot access 'cart' before initialization

(at least in Chrome, I don't know if this is required by ES6).

Comment: It seems you are right and that the issue has nothing to do with node or mongoose. You have the same error in Firefox if you use let. Many thanks :).